# Accessing the next row in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I am trying to access and change the value of the next row in a datatable using a for loop but I get the error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 247.
```

I know that in the final loop, it wont find the next row. But Im checking it if it exists and then only modify the values, but it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  DataRow _row = dt.Rows[i];
  if (_row[1].ToString() != "" && _row[0].ToString() != "")
  {
    int temp = i + 1;
    if (dt.Rows[temp].GetType() == typeof(DataRow))
    {
        dt.Rows[temp][0] = _row[0].ToString();
     }
   }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just loop up until `Rows.Count - 1`, then you don't have to check if there's a next row, since there always will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because there is no row to get, so it fails even before the call to `GetType`:

```
if (dt.Rows[temp].GetType() == typeof(DataRow))
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <-- throws an IndexOutOfRangeException here
```

Instead you can iterate to one less than the number of rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    DataRow nextRow = dt.Rows[i + 1];
    // ...
}
```

If you want to do something special for the last row, you can do that after the loop.